# Query number of digits on a ggplot axis label?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an odd request. Can I figure out the number of digits on a ggplot axis label from the ggplot object?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10))
p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.01))
p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.001))
p1
p2
```

I'd like to return the number of decimal places on the y axes of `p1` and `p2` along the lines of

```
madeUpFunction(p1)
0.01

madeUpFunction(p2)
0.001
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using RStudio, you can explore around all the different levels of a ggplot object with View.

```
View(p2)
```

From there it is just a matter of drilling down using GUI button/arrows to get the attribute you're searching for. This example will be found under scales since that is where it is specified above. On far right is small square to print the code to console on how to index the level. From there it is just adding as generic function

```
get_accuracy_from_ggplot <-  function(x){
    accuracy = environment(environment(x[["scales"]][["scales"]][[1]][["labels"]])[["f"]])[["accuracy"]]
    accuracy
}

get_accuracy_from_ggplot(p1)
get_accuracy_from_ggplot(p2)
```

Comment: Just a note that this only works when you've set the scales yourself (I think). E.g. this doesn't work with `ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()`. If you use `ggplot_build` first, you may be able to find it in there.